# Making ggplot look as nice as the native plot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, visualization, graph-visualization

I have started using ggplot because I heard it's a lot more flexible and looks a lot better than the native plot function. However, my results `ggplot` graph looks worse than `plot` function so I must be doing something wrong. For example, the labels are too small to be legible, the line does not have any points on it, and the ratio just looks better with the default `plot` function. I am new to data visualization, so any guide  or suggestions to making the graph look better would be much appreciated.

With `plot`:

```
plot(table(month(data$DATE)), type="b", 
  main="Time vs. Freq", 
  xaxt='n',
  xlab="Month",
  ylab="Frequency")
axis(1, at=1:9, labels = month.name[1:9])
```

[image: with plot]

With `ggplot`:

```
x <- month(data$DATE)
df = data.frame(x)
df$y <- 1
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = "line") + xlab("Month") + ylab("Freq") + ggtitle("Time vs. Freq")
```

[image]

Comment: can we have a reproducible example please?

Comment: A reproducible example as in the dataset?

Comment: yup. Also, you could edit your question to say specifically what you want to change about the ggplot graph (as you started to in the comments below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely clear what you don't like about the default ggplot2 plots but have you tried one of the other themes?

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = "line") + 
            xlab("Month") + ylab("Freq") + ggtitle("Time vs. Freq")
p + theme_bw() # For black/white publications plots
```

Or grab more themes and experience

```
install.packages("ggthemes") 
library(ggthemes) 
p + theme_tufte()      # Based on Tufte's ideas
p + theme_stata()      # Resembles plots from stata
p + theme_economist()  # A la plots in the economist
```

just to show a few examples. And they can be tweaked as you please

Comment: Ah thank you. I just wasn't sure if my way of doing it was the standard way of making graph, and whether there was a easier or more standard way of doing it. Themes look very helpful! My main concern was that the labels are too small to be legible, and the the lines do not have the points in them. I imagine those were configurable, but I just wanted to make sure that those have to be configured instead of me missing the correct, easier way of doing the same task.

Comment: for the points: `+ geom_points()`.  For the labels: `theme_set(theme_bw(base_size=16))` (or something like that)